# Несколько моделей в одном представлении

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Добрый день,

Я использую пример TPT наследования, у родительского класса есть два дочерних подкласса. Мне нужно реализовать следующую логику, пользователь по желанию может выбрать одну из конкретной модели CreditCard или BankAccout и сохранить ее в бд.

```
public abstract class BillingDetail
{
    public int BillingDetailId { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}

[Table("BankAccounts")]
public class BankAccount : BillingDetail
{
    public string BankName { get; set; }
    public string Swift { get; set; }
}

[Table("CreditCards")]
public class CreditCard : BillingDetail
{
    public int CardType { get; set; }
    public string ExpiryMonth { get; set; }
    public string ExpiryYear { get; set; }
}

public class InheritanceMappingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BillingDetail> BillingDetails { get; set; }
}
```